# Dependent input text codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, text, input, types

Hi am working with codeigniter and i want to make dependent input text like this example below:

i have three fields numberphone, Name, Society and i want to auto fill Name and Society when the user enter the numberphone:

here is the structure of my table in Mysql:

Person (id,numberphone,name,society)

S in a form like this: That's my view:

The View

```
<table>
            <tr>
               <td valign="top">Telephone<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
               <td>
                 <input type="text" name="telephone" class="text" id="telephone"/>
                  <?php echo form_error('telephone'); ?>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td valign="top">Usager<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="usager" class="text" id="usager" readonly="readonly">
                  <?php echo form_error('nbcas'); ?>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td valign="top">society<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="society" class="text" id="society" readonly="readonly">
                  <?php echo form_error('nbcas'); ?>
               </td>
            </tr>

               <td><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/></td>
            </tr>

         </table>
```

My Controller:

```
public function GetUsager()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {

        $telephone = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['row'] = $this->structure->GetUsagerId($telephone);



        header('Content-Type: application/json',TRUE);
        //echo(json_encode($this->structure->GetUsagerId($usager)));
       // echo json_encode($data['usager']);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

and my Model

```
function GetUsagerId ($telephone)
  {
     $this->db->select('name','society');
     $this->db->where('numberphone',$telephone);
     $query=$this->db->get('Person');



     if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
     {

         $row = $query->row();
         return $row;

     }
```

}

jquery code in the view

```
$('#telephone').keyup(function() {
 var phone = $('#telephone').val();
 var baseurl = "<?= base_url(); ?>";
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : baseurl+"index.php/main/GetUsager",
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : phone,
            success: function(data) {
                   $("#usager").append(data.row);

            }
        });

    });
```

Nothing happenned.

Comment: i can't auto fill the name et society fields when i put the numberphone value.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request code:

```
        $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : baseurl+"index.php/main/GetUsager",
        dataType: 'json',
        data    : phone,
        success: function(data) {
               $("#usager").append(data.row);

        }
```

You should change `$("#usager").append(data.row)` to `$("#usager").val(data.row.name)`.

**EDIT:** You should also change `data: phone` to `data: "phone=" + phone`.

Also I think you should reference `data.row.name` to read the name. I have changed from `data.row` to `data.row.name`. Check how you are formatting your JSON output.

Comment: i add the your following intructions but there is no changes.

Comment: what you're meaning when you say Check how you are formatting your JSON output.

Comment: The query row object is something like `$row = {name: "foo", society: "bar"}`. 
So by encoding $data (which has `$data['row'] = $row`) you will have a javascript object like this `{row : {name: "foo", society: "bar"}}`.
To read the name you should access like this `data.row.name`.

Comment: Is your success function called? Did you try putting an alert to confirm it is called?

Comment: i change the json farmat to:$rows= $this->structure->GetUsagerId($telephone);
            $data = array('row'=>$rows);
            header('Content-Type: application/json',TRUE);
            echo json_encode($data);

Comment: i try this :success: function(data) {
                      // $('#usager').val(data.row.name);
                       alert('success');

Comment: No the alert does not appear.

Comment: If your ajax call is really being called then it is returning an error. It is probable that something is wrong with your javascript script. Now you should check that your keyup event is invoked. Put an alert to check.

Comment: i removed all the code and i put only the alert. its works.(the keyup)